# Form Name Is Changed In Visual Studio 2017 Many Errors Occured

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want my form name to be changed and I do that, But Now This Screen is there ..

[image: Error Page In Designer Screen]

While when I open Code it appeared something messy and I don't want to touch it..

[image: Designer Code Errors]

Please Help me with possible way out if exist...

Comment: Have you inherited `IDisposable`?

Comment: How did you change the form name?

Comment: You can't really assume that anything can go well when you have 443 compile errors.  Start at the top of the list or restore from source control.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just right clicked on form and renamed it.. After That A Dialogue Box Was Created And I Pressed YES..

Comment: Go back to your backup (-:) and then use the Solution Explorer to rename the file. VS will offer to rename the class. Also, use those |> buttons to find out that a form uses 2 .cs files.

Answer (score 2):

I Have Figured Out My Way Out I renamed it back and again renamed it back without changing any references ...

[image: Feeling Good]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got all the errors is that Windows Forms Form classes actually consist of two files (3 if you count the resources file). One will have your form name and one will be called your form name with Designer added to it.

E.G.

Form1.cs
Form1.Designer.cs

[image: Solution Explorer view]

These are partial classes. Form1.cs relies on Form1.Designer.cs. Form1.Designer.cs contains all the code to add all your controls to your form (these are then added by the call to `InitializeComponent();` in your main class.

If you rename `Form1.cs` it should also rename `Form1.Designer.cs` (and the .resx file).

If you change the name of the class within `Form1.cs` to something else:

E.G.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
```

This will cause the errors you saw because `Form1.Designer.cs` will still have the name of the class being `Form1`

E.G.

```
partial class Form1 : Form
```

To fix the errors you just open the `Form1.Designer.cs` file and change the name of your class to whatever you changed it to in your main form code, in our example you would change it to:

```
partial class MyForm : Form
```

This will stop all the errors from appearing.

If you rename a form file, make sure you rename it in Visual Studio via Solution Explorer as this should then rename the underlying files too. It may also prompt you about renaming the contained class to the same name.

If it doesn't you can always change the name of the class in the main form file and then press Ctrl+. to bring up the Quick Actions menu, from here you should see an option to rename the entire class.

Here I've renamed Form5 to MyForm:

[image: Rename]

Select the option from the menu and it will automatically rename your form in the .Designer.cs file for you.

Answer (score 0):

when the error comes

1.ctrl+f
2.find for the old name in entire project(eg: Form1)
3.replace all the remaining 'old name' with the 'new name' in entire project manually